# Is there a calendar plugin for tablet?

Tags: jquery-mobile, fullcalendar, tablet

I am working on a scheduler specific to iPad3 Tablet using jQuery Mobile. Can someone please suggest a calendar plugin which is tablet friendly? I have tried [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), but the drag and drop functionality in there is not working, and I am unable to select the start time and end time while swiping the container.

Anyone any sort of solution for this? Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This one works great: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am looking for a scheduler kind of plugin, like [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). Do you have your expert suggestion on that?

Comment: Ah, I see your problem now. I don't think there are any mobile-friendly calendars with drag and drop. Their is a mobile version of the jquery ui datepicker that you might be able to work with, it can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Check this - I don't think it is jQuery, but might suit your needs.
http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml

Also, there are many such plugin's which work with Sencha Touch - you could check those. There may be some which are compatible with both ExtJS and jQuery.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link. I am looking for a solution that works on mobile/tablet and desktops. That was the reason why I choose jQuery mobile and jquery calendars. But scheduler that you send is a javascript based to it should do. Let me have my hands on it. Thanks a lot.